# Leaflet does not seem to print all markers?

Tags: r, leaflet

I am printing a map in R/leaflet and am missing markers. In the example below there should be around 100 markers, but I see only a fraction thereof. What am I missing?

```
library(leaflet)
library(data.table)
library(nycflights13)

data(flights); data(airports)
setDT(flights); setDT(airports)

dest.counts = flights[, .N, by = dest]
dest.counts = merge(dest.counts, airports, by.x = "dest", by.y = "faa", all.x = T)

leaflet(dest.counts) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(radius = sqrt(dest.counts$N) * 200, popup = ~name) %>%
  setView(-95.31, 28.81, zoom = 4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are "missing" the missing values (`NA`). Removing them will plot all circles:

```
leaflet(na.omit(dest.counts)) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(radius = sqrt(dest.counts$N) * 200, popup = ~name) %>%
  setView(-95.31, 28.81, zoom = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer - This is very subtle as when R invokes leaflet, there is no indication that it stops plotting after encounter NAs.